# Can't pass a variable from app.js to another file in node

Tags: node.js, express, module.exports

I am trying to pass a variable from my app.js to another file but i always get the same output {}. I know this can be done the other way around if I put all the database associated code in the other file and then export the variables I need from there. But why doesn't this works?

app.js

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
const cors = require('cors');
const mysql = require('mysql');
const session = require('express-session');
const MySQLStore = require('express-mysql-session')(session);
const userRouter = require('./userRoutes');
const app = express();

app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended: true}));
app.use(cors());
app.disable('x-powered-by');

const pool = mysql.createPool({
    connectionLimit: 10,
    host: "localhost",
    user: "root",
    password: "12345",
    database: "shop"
});
const sessionStore = new MySQLStore({},pool);

app.use(session({
  secret: 'ultimatesecret',
  resave: false,
  saveUninitialized: false,
  store: sessionStore
}));

app.use('/User',userRouter);

app.get('/',(req,res) => {
    pool.getConnection((err,con) => {
        if (err) throw err;
        console.log("Connected as id " + con.threadId);
    })
    res.send('Hello World')
})
app.listen(9999,'0.0.0.0',() => {
    console.log('Server is up and running on port 9999');
});

module.exports = pool;
```

The other file:

```
const pool = require('./app');
const mysql = require('mysql');

console.log(pool);
```

The ouput is {}

Comment: Probably you have a circular dependency that causes the `require()` to not be able to get the exports you want.  You don't show enough code for us to advise on the proper way to  fix, but usually the solution is to break out some common code into a third file that both other files can import with the circular dependency.

Comment: @jfriend00 Yes that was the problem. I thought I hadn't a circular dependency but it was hidden pretty well at least for me. Thank you!!!